# Рандомизатор чисел на js или jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть такой код

```
function randomInteger(min, max) {
    var rand = min - 0.5 + Math.random() * (max - min + 1)
    rand = Math.round(rand);
    return rand;
  }
alert( randomInteger(5, 10) );
```

Нужно его подстроить под вывод в нужный span по классу. От 1000 до 9999 (четырехзначное число должно быть). Подскажите принцип, как реализовать.

Comment: *Подскажите принцип, как реализовать.* У функции два параметра. У вас в условиях 2 числа. Осталось не перепутать...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вывод в `span` можно реализовать через `getElementById` или `getElementsByClassName`, но при поиске по классу нужно указывать индекс этого элемента, так как их может быть несколько, лучше использовать поиск по `id`.

```js
function randomInteger(min, max) {
  var rand = min - 0.5 + Math.random() * (max - min + 1)
  rand = Math.round(rand);
  return rand;
}

document.getElementById('span-id').innerHTML = randomInteger(1000, 9999);

document.getElementsByClassName('span-class')[0].innerHTML = randomInteger(1000, 9999);
```

```html
<span id="span-id"></span>
<br/>
<span class="span-class"></span>
```

Comment: Понял) спасибо, работает, только врываюсь в JS, поэтому такие простые задачи еще не умею делать :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('span.class').text(randomInteger(5,10));
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот так можно любые числа + мини-валидация.

```js
function randomInteger(min, max) {
    var rand = min - 0.5 + Math.random() * (max - min + 1)
    rand = Math.round(rand);
    document.getElementsByClassName('random')[0].innerHTML = `Случайное число ${rand}`;
  }

 document.getElementsByClassName('startRandom')[0].addEventListener('click', ()=> {
           let min = document.getElementsByClassName('min')[0].value;
           let max = document.getElementsByClassName('max')[0].value;
           if(min < max) {
            randomInteger(min, max);
           } else {
           document.getElementsByClassName('random')[0].innerHTML = 'Ведите валидные числа'
           }
 });
```

```css
.random, div {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class='random'></div>

<div>min: <input type="number" class='min'></div>
<div>max: <input type="number" class='max'></div>
<button class='startRandom'>RANDOM!</button>
```

Comment: Очень крутой вариант)! Спасибо

Comment: Тот человек сверху прислал первым, извини)